# How can I removed styling the javascript prompt?

Tags: javascript

I have applied the following code in javascript to pop-up a input box for the user:

Javascript code:

```
var removeDate=prompt("Please enter remove date",curr_date);
```

But somehow this is come out with 2 thing that I would like to removed it from the prompt, which is the "Explorer User Prompt" and "Script Prompt:"

[image]

Does Anyone know how can I do it? so that I can removed both "Explorer User Prompt" and "Script Prompt:" and resize the pop-up box?

Comment: They're still using these things?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately, I don't believe that you can remove either the title or the "Script Prompt" in the dialog box.

These browser limitations are probably there for security reasons, so that you can't make a JavaScript prompt look like something else in an attempt to trick the user. For that same reason, I don't think you can re-size the prompt window.

If you want to style a prompt, I'd look for a JavaScript UI widget that did this via DOM manipulation rather than an actual call to `prompt()`. This is [one example](http://www.anyexample.com/webdev/javascript/ie7_javascript_prompt%28%29_alternative.xml).

Comment: As an addition (not to take anything away from this very right answer):  Or use a jQuery UI dialog.  Or a Qtip2.  Or a colorbox.  There are *dozens* of solutions.

Comment: That is why I mentioned "this is *one* example."

Comment: I know...  I'm agreeing with you and gave you your +1.  Just attempting to add some context.  : )

Comment: Yes, these "limitations" (same for Alert and Confirm) are definitely there on purpose for security reasons.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot style the browser's prompt windows. However, you can use a custom prompt window (such as the jQuery [Impromptu](http://trentrichardson.com/Impromptu/index.php) plugin) instead.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest not using the prompt to being with.  Perhaps the jQuery UI dialog box might be more suiting?

[dialog box](http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/)

Answer (score 0):

You can't style that.

Use a custom one.

Keep in mind a custom one won't work quite like the default one, i.e. locking the browser whilst waiting for user input. It will need to use a callback.